# Start or End of week in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am looking for a way of getting the start of the week relative to today in Actionscript using (and currently stuck with) Flex 4.1. In Java I would do this using the Calendar class via:-

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            1);
    return cal.getTime();
```

I can't seem to find any solution that is anywhere as elegant - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two classes, of the same name, `DateTimeFormatter`. One is a pure Actionscript class, the other is a new class added to Flex 4.5 that wraps the Actionscript version. The [Flex version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html) does some of the heavy lifting for you.

There is a [`getFirstWeekday()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html#getFirstWeekday%28%29) method, it will be respective of the locale you specify.

[Edit]
I got carried away, didn't answer your question specifically. I'm not aware of anything more elegant than the DateTimeFormatter. But from there you can use a [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) object to get the current time, and get what you're after.

There are a handful of date utilities, but I'm not aware of this particular solution. Are you looking for something like this:

```
var timeFormatter:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT, DateTimeStyle.NONE, DateTimeStyle.SHORT);
var firstDay:int = timeFormatter.getFirstWeekday()
var now:Date = new Date();
var dayDelta:int = now.day - firstDay;
var firstDayInMillis:Number = now.time - (dayDelta * 86400 * 1000);
// you can construct a new Date from here: var first:Date = new Date(firstDayInMillis);
```

Comment: Sort of, I'm looking at getting the date object for the start of the week rather than just the string. Just found a third party libary http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/asdoc/org/as3commons/lang/DateUtils.html#getStartOfWeek() which may be what I'm looking for, but yet to confirm.

Comment: There's no String's involved in the above code :) The Date object returns an epoch time in milliseconds. Once you have that, you can use the integer representing the first day of the week to figure out the desired time in milliseconds. Then if necessary, reuse or make a new Date Object our of that time.

Comment: Only using the `DateFormatter` to get the first day of week, which will be respective of the user's locale. Perhaps you could use this with the nifty code in as3commons :)

Comment: Oops, you are quite right... I'm not too bothered with locale as they will all be in the same one for this instance but in the interests of solving I think that along with stuff in comments does it!